# What's the difference between $VAR and $(VAR) in gitlab yaml and makefile

Tags: makefile, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm working on a gitlab pipeline with a makefile. In the yaml file, there are environment variables defined as $VAR = 'var' (for example), but in the makefile they're referenced as $(VAR).

I tried to print to the command line via echo in the pipeline to see if they were the same. When I did, $VAR printed 'var' as expected, but $(VAR) printed VAR: Command not found.

Is there a difference between the two? Or are they actually the same in the yaml and makefiles but I misused echo?

Thank you!

Comment: the later is called variable targeting. It's a syntax to target variables.  You're targeting VAR variable defined in the yaml file. On executing the later ``$(VAR)`` will be substituted with the value as: ``var``. I hope I'm not wrong.

Comment: you are completely wrong @OMiShah

Comment: YAML itself has no sense at all of variables, whether internal or from the environment.  It's just a structured data format, much like JSON and in the same general category as XML.  Whatever you're looking at in the YAML file is characteristic of a particular application's usage of YAML.

Comment: @UpAndAdam completely wrong, my bad, that's sad. Please explain the difference then.

Comment: i did below @OMiShah

Comment: @UpAndAdam, yes I noticed later. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above the expansion of a variable depends on where it is being expanded.

**Makefile**:

`$(VAR)` and `${VAR}` will expand to the value stored in `VAR` (which will be `var`)

`$VAR` will expand to the value stored in `V` followed by `AR` (so, unless you specified a variable named `V`, it will expand to the literal `AR` -- just mentioning it here as this is a common mistake people make)

`$${VAR}` or `$$VAR` will expand to the literals `${VAR}` and `$VAR` respectively.   This can be used to defer the expansion of the variable until bash is running (see below for an example)

**bash or sh (or within a makefile recipe line):**

`$VAR` or `${VAR}` will expand to the value stored in the bash variable `VAR`

`$(VAR)` will run the command `VAR`

**Example:**

Makefile:

```
VAR1 := var1

foo:
    echo var1=$(VAR1)
    VAR2=var2; echo $$VAR2
    VAR3="echo running var3";  echo $$($$VAR3)
```

when foo is run, the first recipe line will be expanded to `echo var1=var1` *by make*, and this will be passed to the shell, and the shell will output `var1=var1`

The second recipe line will run, and make will pass `VAR2=var2; echo var2=$VAR2` to the shell, and the shell will output `var2=var2`.   Note that you have to access a bash variable from the same recipe line as it was set in -- the value will not persist to the next recipe line.

The last recipe line will pass `VAR3="echo running var3";  echo $($VAR3)` to the shell.   From the shell, `$VAR3` is expanded to `echo running var3`, and then `$(echo running var3)` is run as a command, outputting `running var3`, which is then echoed again.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's super helpful. Just to clarify, if I want to move a bash command from the makefile to yaml and the makefile uses $(VAR), when I move the line do I keep it as $(VAR) then? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing echo.  `$(..)` is one the syntaxes for applying `macros` ( variables ) in Makefile rules (targets and prerequisites), but in the recipes (the command line (`bash`)) `$(...)` is command expansion and will evaluate the contents unless it is escaped properly.  That's occurring if you are trying to `echo $(VAR)` from within a recipe because `VAR` is not a command. However if you used `echo "$(VAR)"` it would work properly because the quotes around it say that should perform variable expansion before echoing. To avoid confusion I tend to always use the '${}' syntax for variables so I don't encounter a problem of context in my recipes.